# How to make the new added unbound column value auto number become static?

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, devexpress

First I make an unbound column in `GridView` (using DevExpress):

```
public void buttonl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //GridColumn clmn = gridaaa.Columns["code"];

    if (gridaaa.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("idx") != null)
    {
        gridaaa.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("idx").Dispose();
    }



    GridColunn unbColumn2 = gridaaa.Columns.AddField("idx");
    unbColumn2.VisibleIndex = gridaaa.Columns.Count;
    unbColumn2.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Integer;
    //// Disable editing.
    unbColumn2.OptionsColunn.AllowEdit = false;
    // gridaaa.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("idx").Dispose();
}
```

In the `gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData` event I am using this code

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Column.FieldName == "idx")
    {
        e.Value = e.ListSourceRowIndex;
    }
}
```

for the output or result was:

[image: index column]

The question is how to make the index or idx column value become static when I click sorting in any column header. As you can see when I click genre header the value follow with code or index in database, I want to make it like autonumber from 0 whenever I keep click column header of genre or anything:

[image]

Comment: means you have to recreate index value on sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ColumnView.GetRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowHandletopic) method to get the handle of current row which is always reflects to the position of row in `GridView` from up to down.

Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "idx")
        e.Value = gridView1.GetRowHandle(e.ListSourceRowIndex);
}
```